# Vim: Insert or Append with indendation

Tags: vim

When I am adding a line via `O` or `o` it is added according to the indentation around it.

Is there a way to do the same when using `A` or `I`?

```
class
  def method
▋                  | cursor starts in the first column
  end
end
```

... *clickety-click* ...

```
class
  def method
    ▋              | cursor is correctly positioned inside the method
  end
end
```

`O` and `o` do that out of the box but then I have to start at the line higher/lower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `S` or `cc` to start insert mode at the right indentation level.

Comment: Instead of 'cc' you can also use 'C' (uppercase 'c').

Answer (score 6):

And you can always use `CTRL-F` in insert mode to go to the indentation level computed by vim.

Comment: This is like `==` but in the insert mode, thanks, didn't know that. But I wanted to start the line with the proper indentation, so it's either `S` or `cc` it seems.

Comment: Actually, this is related to `:h 'cinkeys'`